# I am not able to see warning and error pop up messages in Matlab?

Tags: 15.04, matlab

Since I have installed MATLAB in Ubuntu 15.04 I can't see the pop up messages such as warnings or errors that you get while coding. For example, I am supposed to get a message about that a variable is not being used, but instead I get a blank rectangle like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to see what is the message because this tool is pretty useful.

Comment: could you fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was posted here: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116987-empty-tooltips-in-code-analyzer

It seems that problems occur when you are using multiple monitors. I can confirm that when I put Matlab on my laptop screen I do see tooltips, and on my monitor I don't.

Comment: Wow that sucks.  I just confirmed for me as well - it's because of the multiple monitors.  It's not a deal breaker for me because I need multiple monitors more than the tooltips, but it's still quite annoying.  Thank you. +1.